# PHPMailer send() function crashes on live server but not XAMPP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been reading through SO trying to find an answer to my PHPMailer issue.

I am using the latest PHPMailer code and I have my code in a try and catch block. I am using the same SMTP credentials on both the XAMPP hosted site and the 1&1.co.uk hosted site. I have also tried printing debug to a file and know the script gets as far as the `$mail->send()` section, but then all I get back is a page saying:

> The www.reasonstobejolly.com page isn’t working
>
> www.reasonstobejolly.com didn’t send any data.

No exceptions or anything thrown. Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

```
require '../../../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;   // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '##########';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '##########';       // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('orders@reasonstobejolly.com', 'Orders at Reasons to be Jolly');
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $firstName." ".$lastName);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('enquiries@reasonstobejolly.com', 'Order Enquiry');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "Your Order Has Been Received";
    $mail->Body    = "Dear ".$firstName." ".$lastName."<br/>"
    . "Your order has been received; it will be processed as soon as possible      and should be with you in the timeframe specified in our shipping guidelines.<br/>

    ";
    if (isset($randomPassword)) {
        $mail->Body    .= "<p>Username: $email</p><p>Password: $randomPassword</p>";
    }


    $mail->Body    .= "<p>Order Reference : $transactionId<br/>
    Order Date      : ".date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($orderTime))."</p>

    <p>BILL TO:<br/>
    $shipToName <br/>
    $shipToStreet<br/>
    $shipToCity<br/>
    $shipToState<br/>
    $shipToZip<br/>
    </p>
    <p>
    DELIVER TO:<br/>
    $shipToName <br/>
    $shipToStreet<br/>
    $shipToCity<br/>
    $shipToState<br/>
    $shipToZip<br/>
    </p>

    <table>
    <tr><td>Qty</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td></tr>";
    $orderOverviewID = getOrderOverviewIDByPayPalReference($transactionId);

    $orderItemsArray = getItemsByOrderOverviewID($orderOverviewID);
    $postage = 0;
    foreach ($orderItemsArray as $id => $order) {

        $productEmail = getProductByProductID($order->productID);
        $postageAmount = getPostageByPostageID($productEmail->postageID);
        $mail->Body .= "<tr><td>".$order->itemQuantity."</td>"
            . "<td>".$productEmail->productName."</td>"
            . "<td>&pound;".  (getDimensionByID(getColourByID($order->colourID)->dimensionID)->dimensionPrice) * $order->itemQuantity."</td></tr>";
        if ($postageAmount->postagePrice > $postage) {
            $postage = $postageAmount->postagePrice;
        }
    }
    // these are from create invoice.

    $vat = $amt * 0.2;
    $subtotal = $amt - $postage;
    // TODO VAT and postage need to be calculated in the Paypal bit.
    $mail->Body .= "<tr><td></td><td align='right'>Sub Total:</td>     <td>&pound;$subtotal</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td align='right'>Standard Delivery:</td><td>&pound;$postage</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td align='right'>(Including VAT @ 20%):</td><td>&pound;$vat</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td align='right'>GRAND TOTAL:</td><td>&pound;$amt</td></tr>
    </table>


    If you have a query, or require further information, please contact Customer Service at: http://www.reasonstobejolly.com";

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: I have done some more debug chasing and it craps out at                 protected function smtpSend($header, $body)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after a phone call to 1and1.co.uk, that the only mail option they support is mail(). They told me that PHPMailer will not work on their servers.